# How to add a form that appears after clicking on all the buy buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

to be more precise the form apear only on the first id="my-form" of the page , for example if my first button with id="my-form" and also the second button with the same id ,then the form will apear only on the first button and does't work on the other buttons.

thanks in advance!!!!!!!

```js
const openForm = document.getElementById("my-form")
exitForm = document.getElementById("close-buy-form")
main = document.querySelector("main")

openForm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    main
        .classList
        .add("body-btn");
})
exitForm.addEventListener("click", () => {
    main
        .classList
        .remove("body-btn");
})
```

```css
main.body-btn {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <img class="exit-btn" id="exit-btn-js" src="/assets/exit.svg" alt="">
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a data-link="home" class="normal-a nav-link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="about" class="normal-a nav-link">About</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="products" class="normal-a nav-link">Products</a></li>
        <li><a data-link="reviews" class="normal-a nav-link">Reviews</a></li>
        <li class=" buy-now">
            <a href="#order" class="premium-a" id="my-form"><span class="didi">Buy now</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section class="hero">
    <div class="left-hero">
        <h1>Present Your <span>Cool</span> Product</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
        <div class="buy-now">
            <a href="#order" class="didi" id="my-form">BUY NOW</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-hero">
        <img src="/assets/watch-2.png" alt="shoe-6">
    </div>
</section>
```

PS. 1 month of html/css and these tricks of js that shows and hide elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the solution after 3 hours of trying codes ... and i did find that i need to add for each button a different id and that id should've its own const on the 
like in the next code:

```html
<script>
    const openForm = document.getElementById("my-form")
    openForm2 = document.getElementById("my-form-2")
    exitForm = document.getElementById("close-buy-form")
    main = document.querySelector("main")
    

    openForm2.addEventListener("click", () => {
        main
            .classList
            .add("body-btn");
    })
    openForm.addEventListener("click", () => {
        main
            .classList
            .add("body-btn");
    })
    exitForm.addEventListener("click", () => {
        main
            .classList
            .remove("body-btn");
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I don t know JAVASCRIPT , only html and css